# How to static_assert that something is an array (including VLA)?

Tags: c++, g++, gnu

Using GNU extensions.

In C, I have this:

```c
#define is_same_type(a, b)                      \
    __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(a), __typeof__(b))
#define is_array(a)         (!is_same_type((a), &(a)[0]))

#define Static_assert_array(a)                  \
    _Static_assert(is_array(a), "Not a `[]` !")
```

This correctly statically asserts that something is an array.

However, in g++, there is no [`__builtin_types_compatible_p()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

In g++, I had this:

```c
#define Static_assert_array(a)                  \
    static_assert(std::is_array <__typeof__(a)>::value, "Not a `[]`!")
```

But when I tried to use it with a VLA, I found out that it doesn't support VLAs:

```
test.c:10:39: error: ‘int [n]’ is a variably modified type
   10 |  return std::is_array <__typeof__(vla)>::value;
      |                                   ^
test.c:10:39: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class> struct std::is_array’
```

Is there any way to make that macro work with VLAs?

Comment: `alx_is_array` vs `is_array` is this a typo? btw interesting question. VLAs appear quite often in quesitons but it is rare that they are used consciously. I don't think it can be done without a compiler intrinsic. Templates need to know the exact type at compile time and arrays decay to pointers on most occasions, which makes them hard to distinguish

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes, it was a typo. It is the prefix of my library, which I forgot to remove :). Fixed.

Comment: There are no VLAs in C++

Comment: @M.M But there are in g++.